# Uhuntu 22.04 monitor problem.... Monitor is not connected

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, monitor, signal

I am a new user at Ubuntu and just today's morning I installed in on my computer dual boot with windows 10 when ever I try to open my pc the monitor works fine with windows 10 but when I boot uhuntu after 2 seconds my monitor shows cable not connect **no signal** and it works fine with windows....

This is my first of using uhuntu that's why I don't know what to do

I have only one monitor connected with my pc

And I am using a normal VGA cable to connect with the monitor with Integrated graphics of **intel Core i3 10100**
And mother board of **MSI M410 M-HV3**

Comment: I have a similar problem with my monitor although I do not use Windows. Sometimes, Ubuntu shows no signal or resolution not supported and I have to toggle the inputs in the monitor settings one by one until it gets back to the PC (select the different input options). When the PC is selected again in the monitor settings, it recognizes the PC.

Comment: Okay I will try :)